# How to make a simple modal pop up form using jquery and html?

Tags: jquery, html

I already read the tutorials on jquery but I'm having a hard time understanding it is there someone who can teach me more easier, please I want to happen is that when I press one of my buttons its value will display in #valueFromMyButton and when the modal pop out i can type a text and after i click ok the text that I type will be placed on #valueFromMyModal

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="btn1" type="button" value="1">
        <input id="btn2" type="button" value="2">
        <input id="btn3"type="button" value="3">

        <input id="valueFromMyModal" type="text">

        <!--How to make this pop up modal form-->
        <div id="myform">
            <form>
<label id="valueFromMyButton"></label>
            <input id="name" type="text">
            <input id="btnOK" type="button" value="Ok">
            </form>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: for better solution, i think you can use jQuery UI dialog widgets

Comment: Check jquery ui dialog
http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: so hard to understand any tuts that is much easier

Comment: you can check this out. http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/04/08/basic-usage-of-the-jquery-ui-dialog/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have placed here  complete bins for above query. you can check demo link too.

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp78/2/How%20to%20make%20a%20simple%20modal%20pop

**HTML**

```
<div id="panel">
  <input type="button" class="button" value="1" id="btn1">
  <input type="button" class="button" value="2" id="btn2">
  <input type="button" class="button" value="3" id="btn3">
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="valueFromMyModal">
  <!-- Dialog Box-->
  <div class="dialog" id="myform">
    <form>
      <label id="valueFromMyButton">
      </label>
      <input type="text" id="name">
      <div align="center">
        <input type="button" value="Ok" id="btnOK">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $(".button").click(function() {
        $("#myform #valueFromMyButton").text($(this).val().trim());
        $("#myform input[type=text]").val('');
        $("#myform").show(500);
    });
    $("#btnOK").click(function() {
        $("#valueFromMyModal").val($("#myform input[type=text]").val().trim());
        $("#myform").hide(400);
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.button{
  border:1px solid #333;
  background:#6479fd;
}
.button:hover{
  background:#a4a9fd;
}
.dialog{
  border:5px solid #666;
  padding:10px;
  background:#3A3A3A;
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
}
.dialog label{
  display:inline-block;
  color:#cecece;
}
input[type=text]{
  border:1px solid #333;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:5px;
}
#btnOK{
  border:1px solid #000;
  background:#ff9999;
  margin:5px;
}

#btnOK:hover{
  border:1px solid #000;
  background:#ffacac;
}
```

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp78/2/How%20to%20make%20a%20simple%20modal%20pop

Comment: if I want a to put a "x" or something "close" at the top right of the pop up form? Where should i put it in the function?

Answer (score -1):

I came across this question when I was trying similar things.

A very nice and simple sample is presented at w3schools website.

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal&stacked=h

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```