# How to open a div element from other view in to a jquery modal window?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the view `form.html.erb` with a `div id="form"`, but I have another view `main.html.erb` with a button, I want to click the button and open the `div "form"` in to a jquery modal window **but without leaving the main view**. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you check [Twitter Bootstrap Modal](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-modals.php)

Comment: use ajax to load the view

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a simple modal pop up form using jquery and html?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421849/how-to-make-a-simple-modal-pop-up-form-using-jquery-and-html)

Comment: I know how to make a simple modal pop up with jquery, but I need to call an element from other page (view) in my actual view, thats my problem., thank you if anybody can show me the code.. I've read something about the load() function, but Im not sure if that solve my problem and how can use it in ruby on rails, all examples that I found is for php.

Comment: It is the most common question now a days so please see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Bootstrap model with Ajax call. It is not possible using just query here is the reason behind it: When you call a view it requires to complete the associated code written in controller and that's why you have to send a request first though Ajax and then replace the content accordingly.